# Laravel pagination is not working after first page

Tags: laravel, pagination

I am developing one luggage management application. When I try to paginate shipments details in reports it is not working properly. It works fine in first page but when I click second page link it is showing blank page.

[ReportsController.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4D65N.png)

[parcelreport.blade.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYKkv.png)

my route is

[web.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syioX.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because you are using post in your route. Once you click on a link, your browser redirects but its just loading the view from the first route you created and not running through the post one that uses the controller. Try changing the URL of the second route and set it to get so you can actually process the second, third... pages with the controller. Or make all request run through the controller and check if `$request->to` and `$request->from` exist as to whether you should make a DB query or not.

Comment: Thank for the explanation. It helped me. Actually I am also making a post request from view so I could not make it as get. But I deleted the first route and called balde through Controller. I used route "any". Then it is working well.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. What did you change to "any"? Could you please add some ss to show what did you change? Thanks.

Comment: I meant Route::any('your-url', 'yourcontroller@method'). Let me know if you need more help

Answer (score 5):

You can try this. Hope this might help you

```
{{ $shipments->appends(Request::all())->links() }}
```

Comment: When I do Request::all() it also displays token value in URL. Will it be a good approach?

Comment: In that case you can use the `except` method. Use `{{ $shipments->appends(Request::except('token'))->links() }}`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to append the `to` and `from` to the links.

```
{{ $shipments->appends(['from' => $from, 'to' => $to])->links() }}
```

[Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination#displaying-pagination-results) (scroll down to **Appending To Pagination Links**)

Comment: Yes, I tried with it. My URL is changing but data is not appending.

Comment: I tried {{ $shipments->appends($_GET)->links() }} also. Still not working

Comment: @RajaDurai When it comes to Laravel avoid using superglobals such as `$_GET` and `$_POST` and use the request instead. How are you getting the `to` and `from` variables original? They will only be included in the links if they are already set.

Comment: @RajaDurai Nevermind, I didn't see the web.php image. In future, please will you add your code to your question rather than attaching an image as it does help greatly when it comes to being able to replicate you issue and help with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

$chunk = $collection->forPage(2, 3);/// page number , num of items par page

$chunk->all();

from laravel docs

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-forpage

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar issue recently on laravel 9. i was always seeing only first page of laravel pagination.

turned out that my nginx configuration was missing to include query string.

this was my original nginx.conf which did not work

```
# conf that did not work
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
```

updated it to include query string and it worked.

```
# working conf
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```

note:

not tested but i guess this conf will also not work with laravel pagination

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$args;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case aparently the problem was related with the methods types, It works for me `{{ $items->appends($_GET)->links() }}`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You also use

```
 use Carbon\Carbon;
$fromDate = $request->from_date ?? Carbon::today()->toDateString();
        $toDate = $request->to_date ?? Carbon::today()->toDateString();
        $orders = Order::with('orderDetails', 'journeyDetails', 'user')
            ->whereBetween('created_at', [$fromDate . ' 00:00:00', $toDate . ' 23:59:59'])
            ->paginate(10);
        $orders->appends(['from_date' => $fromDate, 'to_date' => $toDate]);
Then your site url 
http://localhost:8000/admin/sales-report?from_date=2023-12-01&to_date=2023-12-25&page=4
```