# Laravel Pagination does not change the pages

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I wanted to add pagination to my project and followed a tutorial for that. When I click new page the results are not changing.

In my `Controller` I added this `$competitions = Competition::latest()->paginate(1);`

Then into `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider` added this `use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;` and inside the `boot function` added this:  `Paginator::useBootstrap();`

And the last thing was to add this `{{ $competitions->onEachSide(1)->links() }}` after I close my table in the blade file.

EDIT:
Controller function:

```
public function index()
    {
        $competitions = Competition::latest()->paginate(1);
    
        return view('competition.index', compact('competitions')); 
    }
```

Loop in blade:

```
        @foreach ($competitions as $competition)      
    <tbody >
       @switch($competition->status)
            @case('active')
                <tr>
            @break

            @case('to_push')
                <tr class="bg-secondary">
            @break

            @case('inactive')
                <tr class="bg-warning">
            @break

            @default
                <tr>
            @endswitch
            <td>{{ $competition->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $competition->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $competition->status }}</td>
            <td>{{ $competition->mode }}</td>
            <td>{{ $competition->type }}</td>
            <td>{{ $competition->frequency }}</td>
            <td>{{ $competition->last_push }}</td>
            <td>{{ $competition->next_push }}</td>
            <td class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="{{ route('events.list_by_competition',['competition' => $competition->id]) }}">Events</a></td>   
            <td class="text-center"><a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="{{ route('competitions.exports',$competition->id) }}">Exports</a></td>
            <td class="text-center">
                <form action="{{ route('competitions.destroy',$competition->id) }}" method="POST">
    
                    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="{{ route('competitions.edit',$competition->id) }}">Edit</a>
   
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
      
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Delete</button>
                </form>
            </td>
    
        </tr>
 </tbody>
        @endforeach
    </table>
    {{ $competitions->links('pagination::bootstrap-5') }}
```

`dd(Competition::all())` returns the 4 records I have[image]

Can you please tell me what I did wrong? Any and all help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

`$competitions = Competition::latest()->paginate(1)` this command will return you one result and then pagination will take 1 per page so it won't be shown at all.

Try something like this in your controller

```
$competitions = Competition::paginate(1)

return view(...., ['competitions' => $competitions]);
```

and in your blade add this under the foreach loop where you display data

```
{{ $competitions->links() }}
```

[Read more here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/pagination#basic-usage)

**HERE IS HOW TO MAKE PAGINATION**

BLADE

```
@foreach($paginate as $p)
    {{ $p->name }} <br>
@endforeach

{{ $paginate->links() }}
```

CONTROLLER

```
return view('backend.test', [
        'paginate' => Product::paginate(5)
    ]);
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it did not work. Used `return view('competition.index', compact('competitions'), ['competitions' => $competitions]);` and still the pages according to the url change but the items inside the table does not

Comment: hmm compact and ['something' => $something] are doing the same thing so it might be the issue. Can you update you question with whole code from that method in you controller and blade foreach loop? Must see some code to be able to help more :) THanks

Comment: Just edited my question

Comment: Could you please remove this part in controller `latest()->` just leave (for testing purposes) Competition::paginate(1);

Comment: I tried already it shows the first created item but the big problem is still here

Comment: How much entries do you have in the db? Can you please edit question with the screenshot of dd(Competition::all())

Comment: and why are you looping tbody?? ` @foreach ($competitions as $competition)      
    <tbody >`

Comment: you also have closing tr tag but don't have opening one

Comment: Move a tag in actions column outside of the form

Comment: I am looping it because I need to change the color of the row(different status different color)

Comment: I've got 4 records in total. And its giving me 4 pages but changing the page does not change the item inside the table

Comment: Just added the screenshot. It shows all of my records

Comment: @Yorkata008 check answer it is updated. Try to remove that part inside links() and try to manually change page in URL and see if the data will loop.

Comment: Nope the same result appears on every page

Comment: what the... hahahaha getting out of the ideas bro :D

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50957776/laravel-pagination-is-not-working-after-first-page

Comment: I'm telling you men I tried everything including editing the .htaccess file. I'll check the link you sent

Comment: Ugh, I asked a new question since according to the URL the pages change only the items are the same. Thank you so much for your time and ideas

Comment: Your welcome sorry I couldnt help :/